# Why isn't my plt.plot() working when graphing projectile motion?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, physics

I'm graphing projectile motion without/with air friction and I'm now on the first part, which is the one without air friction.

After I've put the plt.plot(x_nodrag,y_nodrag), it suppose to draw a curved line of the projectile motion. But for some reasons it's not being drawn even as the data of the them are being print. I want to know why.

I know there might be a lot of errors in this code!! Feel free to point them out if you'd like to. Thank you guys for the help.

Here's the picture of the graph:https://i.stack.imgur.com/znFLM.png

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Model parameters
M = 1.0          # Mass of projectile in kg
g = 9.8          # Acceleration due to gravity (m/s^2)
V = 80           # Initial velocity in m/s
ang = 60.0       # Angle of initial velocity in degree
Cd = 0.005       # Drag coefficient
dt = 0.5         # time step in s

# Set up the lists to store variables
# Start by putting the initial velocities at t=0
t = [0]                         # list to keep track of time
vx = [V*np.cos(ang/180*np.pi)]  # list for velocity x and y components
vy = [V*np.sin(ang/180*np.pi)]


#show the projectile motion without drag force
t1=0
vx_nodrag=V*np.cos(ang/180*np.pi) 
vy_nodrag=V*np.sin(ang/180*np.pi)

while (t1 < 100):
    x_nodrag=vx_nodrag*t1
    y_nodrag=vy_nodrag*t1+(0.5*-9.8*t1**2)
    plt.ylim([0,200])
    plt.xlim([0,270])
    plt.plot(x_nodrag,y_nodrag)
    print(x_nodrag,y_nodrag)
    t1=t1+dt

plt.show()
```

Comment: You should be looking at [animation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/animation_api.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `plt.plot` does not work for individual points. Use `plt.scatter(x_nodrag, y_nodrag)` instead, or collect the consecutive coordinates into lists or arrays and then plot the entire graph at once.

Comment: `plt.plot` would work if the `fmt` is changed to `'.'`; regardless `scatter` makes more sense